# how to treat regular lumber for outdoor use

Tags: deck, staining, decking, pressure-treated

What are the solutions to stain lumber for outdoor use, except buying pressure-treated wood? What I want to do is take the old lumber, which is still in good shape, but turned gray because of the weather/rain/etc, sand it, and then stain and re-use for decking. What are those stains/paints/etc. called? So I assume there is something I could stain boards with that would prevent it from rot, mould etc.

Comment: What kind of wood is it? If it's a standard kiln-dried whitewood, I think you're out of luck. If it is cedar or another variety of hardwood, it will likely hold up better and there may be real options to help you do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Copper Naphthenate is the stuff I use it looks like a green stain , now o days the % is much lower than in years past so I will apply several coats if in contact with earth but for rails and things not touching earth 1 coat works fine. Edited for correct chemical thanks Jimmy

Comment: It works best if you put the wood in a vacuum chamber, pull out the air then fill and pressurize the chamber with copper solution.

Comment: Jimmy thanks I will edit my answer guess I should have looked at the can instead of trying from memory.+

Comment: Thanks for comments. I think I wasn't very clear about my intentions, so I edited the question, please take a look again.

Comment: Copper napthenate is also available in brown.  It stinks and it stains.  If allowed to air out, the odor fades after a couple weeks.  The brown staining of the wood is not very permanent.  The MSDS has some important warnings.  My [fence post replacement recipe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/129605) has some notes on using it .